deckgl with mapbox: map covering screen only partially
I am experimenting with deckgl and mapbox.
My index.html is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DeckGL + Cesium Ion Tiles Viewer</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #app {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

And index.js:
// Create a Deck.gl TileLayer to display the tileset
const tileLayer = new Tile3DLayer({
  id: 'tile-3d-layer',
  data: '....',
  loader: CesiumIonLoader,
  loadOptions: {
    'cesium-ion': {accessToken: '....'}
  },
  pointSize: 0.5
});

// Create the Mapbox GL JS map
const MAP_STYLE = 'https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/dark-matter-nolabels-gl-style/style.json';

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'app',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
  accessToken: MAPBOX_TOKEN,
  center: [73.851210,
    18.516729],
  zoom: 11
});

map.once('load', () => {
  const deckOverlay = new MapboxOverlay({
    interleaved: true,
    layers: [
      tileLayer
    ]
  });

  map.addControl(deckOverlay);
});

With this set-up, I see that map is covering screen only partially:

I want map to cover entire screen.
What am I missing in my code?
PS: This worked:
html, body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     height: 100%;
}


That style solution makes sense! If in the future you need to display a smaller map and you want to enable a fullscreen mode, check this doc: https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/widgets/fullscreen-widget
